# Rendering a Microsoft Word document on a webpage

Tags: javascript, web-applications, ms-word, latex

I'm designing a web application where a large portion of the site will be displaying user-generated documents. Now, I've already implemented LaTeX source code and pdf rendering on the website, but I am still can't render Microsoft Word files (.doc and .docx) on the site. I've looked around and found a similar question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510148/render-a-microsoft-word-document-in-a-web-browser)), but it was never answered. I'm wondering whether or not using a web-based solution like Google Docs or doing it programatically on the server with OpenOffice are viable solutions. A pure JavaScript solution would be ideal though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on Vikram's answer, you could use [Google Docs Viewer](https://docs.google.com/viewer) in order to render the files. This way it should work on all browsers.

Instead of

```
<a href="doc1.doc" target="awindow">Doc 1</a>
```

use

```
<a href="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=[URLToDoc1.doc]" target="awindow">Doc 1</a>
```

But you have to urlencode the URL. For example,

```
http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable-osdi06.pdf
```

becomes

```
http%3A%2F%2Fresearch.google.com%2Farchive%2Fbigtable-osdi06.pdf
```

You can go to https://docs.google.com/viewer in order to generate the links easily.

Moreover, Vikram's code is old and ugly. You should use something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Open Doc</title>
<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
.clear{clear:both;}
#list{float:left;margin-right:50px;}
#wrapper{overflow:hidden;}
#awindow{width:100%;height:440px;}
/*]]>*/
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="list">
    <li><a href="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=[URLToDoc1.doc]" target="awindow">Doc 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=[URLToDoc2.docx]" target="awindow">Doc 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=[URLToDoc3.doc]" target="awindow">Doc 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="wrapper">
  <iframe id="awindow" name="awindow" src="title.html"></iframe>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this already?:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Open Doc</title>
</head>
<body>
<DIV align="CENTER">
<TABLE BORDER="1" CELLSPACING="1" CELLPADDING="1" WIDTH="100%">
<TR>
<TD WIDTH="25%" ALIGN="left" VALIGN="TOP">
<a href="doc1.doc" target="awindow">Doc 1</A><br>
<a href="doc2.docx" target="awindow">Doc 2</A><br>
<a href="doc3.doc" target="awindow">Doc 3</A>
</TD>
<TD WIDTH="75%" ALIGN="CENTER" VALIGN="TOP">
<iframe name="awindow" frameborder=2 width=580 height=440 src="title.html"></iframe>
</TD></TR></TABLE></CENTER>
</DIV>
</body>
</html>
```

modify the href attributes to path on your server where you will place these documents